# Q3DScatter --> How to add a point with a different color to a point cloud

Tags: c++, qt

I wrote a program in Qt, which visualizes a processed pointcloud (3D-points) by using Q3DScatter. 
Now I want to add calculated keypoints with a different color.
Is that possible?
Does anyboy have some experiences with that?
Below you can see the part of code, where the point cloud is added to the data array.

```
QScatterDataArray * dataArray = new QScatterDataArray;
dataArray->resize(vector_seg_x->size());
QScatterDataItem * ptrToDataArray = &dataArray->first();

for(int i = 0; i < vector_seg_x->size();i++){

    ptrToDataArray->setPosition(QVector3D(
                                    (double)(iter_seg_x[i]),
                                    (double)(iter_seg_y[i]),
                                    (double)(iter_seg_z[i])));
    ptrToDataArray++;

}

m_graph_seg->seriesList().at(0)->dataProxy()->resetArray(dataArray);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only set a color/gradient for a whole point list:

```
Q3DScatter scatter;
scatter.setFlags(scatter.flags() ^ Qt::FramelessWindowHint);

scatter.addSeries(new QScatter3DSeries);
scatter.addSeries(new QScatter3DSeries);

{
    QScatterDataArray *data = new QScatterDataArray;
    *data << QVector3D(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f) << QVector3D(-0.3f, -0.5f, -0.4f) << QVector3D(0.0f, -0.3f, 0.2f);

    scatter.seriesList().at(0)->dataProxy()->resetArray(data);

    QLinearGradient linearGrad(QPointF(100, 100), QPointF(200, 200));
    linearGrad.setColorAt(0, Qt::blue);
    linearGrad.setColorAt(1, Qt::red);

    scatter.seriesList().at(0)->setBaseGradient(linearGrad);
    scatter.seriesList().at(0)->setColorStyle(Q3DTheme::ColorStyle::ColorStyleObjectGradient);
}

{
    QScatterDataArray *data = new QScatterDataArray;
    *data << QVector3D(0.f, 0.f, 0.f);

    scatter.seriesList().at(1)->dataProxy()->resetArray(data);
    scatter.seriesList().at(1)->setBaseColor(Qt::green);
}

scatter.show();
```