# QT. graph by points in qt

Tags: qt

Good afternoon, I need to display the points of the array on the work area as follows - I need the coordinates to be obtained from the indices of the two-dimensional array, and the points themselves are displayed in accordance with the value inside the array cell. For example in grayscale or any other color scheme. is there a ready-made solution in qt?

Comment: What is work area ? Which class do you use to model this ?

Comment: Thanks, already found a solution

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44329125/q3dscatter-how-to-add-a-point-with-a-different-color-to-a-point-cloud